# Get Link-Local Domain Name from IP Address (i.e. Reverse DNS Lookup with Multicast DNS & DNS-SD)

Tags: bonjour, zeroconf, mdns, reverse-dns, dns-sd

I have a server application running on a device on the LAN that is discoverable via DNS-SD (i.e. Zeroconf/Bonjour/Avahi). Client devices, also on the LAN, connect to this server. I have no control over what application is used to connect to my server application, but I do know that they are likely using DNS-SD and mDNS to discover and connect to the server. How can I retrieve the link-local domain name identifying these client devices given only their IP address in C or C++?

According to [RFC 6762 Multicast DNS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762) - [Section 4. Reverse Address Mapping](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762#section-4):
*"Like ".local.", the IPv4 and IPv6 reverse mapping domains are also defined to be link-local...Since names under this domain correspond to IPv4 link-local addresses, it is logical that the local link is the best place to find information pertaining to those names."*

So theoretically, it should be possible to look up the link-local domain names by IP address. Does anyone know how? Maybe I'm not looking in the right places, but I don't see a API call for this within the Bonjour docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up getting an answer to this question via Apple's Bonjour Dev mailing list.

As per *Quinn "The Eskimo!"*, here is how you can do it:

```
static void DNSCallback(
    DNSServiceRef                       sdRef,
    DNSServiceFlags                     flags,
    uint32_t                            interfaceIndex,
    DNSServiceErrorType                 errorCode,
    const char                          *fullname,
    uint16_t                            rrtype,
    uint16_t                            rrclass,
    uint16_t                            rdlen,
    const void                          *rdata,
    uint32_t                            ttl,
    void                                *context
)
{
    const uint8_t *     cursor;

    fprintf(stderr, "DNSCallback\n");
    assert(rrtype == kDNSServiceType_PTR);
    assert(rrclass == kDNSServiceClass_IN);
    cursor = (const uint8_t *) rdata;
    while ( *cursor != 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%.*s.", (int) *cursor, cursor + 1);
        cursor += *cursor + 1;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
}

static void SocketCallBack(CFSocketRef s, CFSocketCallBackType type, CFDataRef address, const void *data, void *info)
{
    DNSServiceErrorType err;

    fprintf(stderr, "SocketCallBack\n");

    err = DNSServiceProcessResult(((AppDelegate *) info)->sdRef);
    fprintf(stderr, "err = %d\n", (int) err);
}

- (IBAction)testAction:(id)sender
{
    DNSServiceErrorType err;
    int                 sock;
    CFSocketRef         cfSock;

    fprintf(stderr, "-[AppDelegate testAction:]\n");

    assert(self->sdRef == NULL);

    err = DNSServiceQueryRecord(
        &self->sdRef,
        kDNSServiceFlagsForceMulticast,
        0,
        "9.40.0.10.in-addr.arpa.",
        kDNSServiceType_PTR,
        kDNSServiceClass_IN,
        DNSCallback,
        self
    );
    fprintf(stderr, "err = %d\n", (int) err);

    sock = DNSServiceRefSockFD(self->sdRef);
    fprintf(stderr, "sock = %d\n", sock);

    CFSocketContext context = { 0, self, NULL, NULL, NULL };

    cfSock = CFSocketCreateWithNative(NULL, sock, kCFSocketReadCallBack, SocketCallBack, &context);
    assert(cfSock != NULL);

    CFRunLoopSourceRef rls;
    rls = CFSocketCreateRunLoopSource(NULL, cfSock, 0);
    assert(rls != NULL);

    CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), rls, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
}
```

This example will find the link-local host name for the IP address 10.0.40.9. The IP address is inserted in reverse order.